# JMock Generic return types

Tags: java, generics, jmock

I'm writing a JMock test for a class that needs to create a number of collections within itself. I am supplying the class with a factory which will generate a Collection when needed.

```
interface Factory
{
    <T> Collection<T> newCollection();
}

class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(Factory f)
    {
        List<ThingA> la = f.newCollection();
        List<ThingB> lb = f.newCollection();
    }
}
```

Now that works but when using JMock to test "MyClass", I cannot mock this return type overloading.

```
Collection<ThingA> ta = new LinkedList<ThingA>();
Collection<ThingB> tb = new LinkedList<ThingB>();
Collection<ThingC> tc = new LinkedList<ThingC>();

Factory mockFactory = context.mock(Factory.class);
context.checking(new Expectations()
{
    {
        allowing(mockFactory).newCollection(); will(returnValue(ta));
        allowing(mockFactory).newCollection(); will(returnValue(tb));
        allowing(mockFactory).newCollection(); will(returnValue(tc));
    }
}
);

// All return ta
Collection<ThingA> ta2 = mockFactory.newCollection();
Collection<ThingB> tb2 = mockFactory.newCollection();
Collection<ThingC> tc2 = mockFactory.newCollection();
```

Is there any way to get this to work? I know I could pass in a ThingX in as an argument but that seems a bit pointless if it's just to trigger type checking for testing.

My current fix is going to be to add a sequence so that I'm enforcing the order of the calls to newCollection but I can see situations where this would not work (say pooling of generic types).

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type erasure is getting in the way to what you are trying to do. I'd simply pass a `ThingX` (or `ThingX.class`) as you mentioned. Unfortunately, type erasure forces you to do that type of *hacky* things.

It's best to think of your code as divided into two domains: generic-aware and generic-unaware, and when you have to glue things together from one the later to the former, there is no way to avoid doing one of the two (for keeping things under control):

either pass parameters just to trigger type checking (as you suggested):

```
Collection<ThingA> ta2 = mockFactory.newCollection(ThingA.class);
Collection<ThingB> tb2 = mockFactory.newCollection(ThingB.class);
Collection<ThingC> tc2 = mockFactory.newCollection(ThingC.class);
```

or encapsulate generics-unaware code into methods that are a) generics-aware, and b) have a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation to suppress the warning you'll get when assigning from one domain to the other.

```
class MockFactoryThingie
{
   /**
    *@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    */
   Collection<ThingA> newThingACollection()
   { 
     return (Collection<ThingA>) ... your generic-unaware collection thing...   
   }
}
```

Either way is clunky. We gotta thank our Java/JCP overlords for bestowing unto us this gem that is type erasure :)

Comment: It's just a shame that Java is able to work out the correct return type because of the reference type you are trying using to store the return, yet JMock cannot do this. I think my code in this area is all generic-aware it's just that JMock cannot work out the generic to use based on return type. I'm not sure your second option would work since I'd need to know all the types I want to create and make functions for them while the generic approach doesn't care. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: Oh, I did miss something. Didn't notice you'd manualled the Mock factory. I was hoping using JMock would mean I could get away from hand making mocks. I guess maybe not :)

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you Matt :) But yeah, I would have to manually fiddle with the mocks if I were to implement what you are seeking. It is a lofty goal, but unfortunately, type erasure makes it impossible in Java. If there wasn't type erasure, then what you seek would be possible. What can I say? Type erasure sucks :)

Comment: It isn't you disappointing me; you're just the bringer of bad news :)